# Remove double space and replace with a single one in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have 2m lines of Uk postcode data but some muppet has used double spaces in some cases and single spaces in others. I need to merge data based on the postcode so it needs to be consistent.

I can't find a simple way to do this in pandas, but it feels like there should be. Any advice?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might be looking for `pd.Series.str.replace`:

```
df.postcode = df.postcode.str.replace('  ', ' ')
```

Comment: If OP wants to replace any number of consecutive spaces with a single one: `df.postcode = df.postcode.str.replace('\s{2,}', ' ')`

Answer (score 7):

this should replace all multiple spaces with a single space

```
df.postcode = df.postcode.str.replace(' +', ' ')
```

remove all spaces from the start and end

```
df.postcode = df.postcode.str.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should replace any kind of spces,tabs,..etc to one space:

```
df.postcode = df.postcode.str.replace('\s+', ' ')
```